# strange symbol in RecursiveIteratorIterator

Tags: php

Hello I have Problem While I Listing Files in folder named upload, When There's arabic file It show `��� ����� ������`

```
           $target = "upload";
    $it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($target));

    while($it->valid()) {

        if (!$it->isDot()) {
            $nom=$nom+1;
            echo $it->getSubPathName();
            echo '<tr align="center"><td> <a href="play.php?fil=' . $it->getSubPathName() . '">Play</a> </td><td>' . $it->getSubPathName() . '</td><td>' . $nom . '</td></tr>'; } }
```

Comment: `utf8_econde()`  should manage this

Comment: you mean `utf8_encode()` - typo :)

Comment: Fabio meant [`utf8_encode()`](http://php.net/utf8_encode) ;-)

Comment: Yeah i meant so, my bad

Comment: now get ÊÚáã ÇááÛÉ ÇáÇäÌáíÒíÉ.mp4

Comment: Check to see if your file is "saved as" UTF-8 and not ANSI @emadiga and with/without BOM.

Comment: @Fred-ii- not worked :(

Comment: It may be important that the file be saved "without" BOM. Do you know if it has it or if it's "with" BOM? @emadiga

Comment: @Fred-ii-yes I am using Dreamweaver and there's check box with BOM and I am sure that not checked

Comment: Can you try the opposite then? @emadiga and try adding `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` in the `<head></head>` of your document.

Comment: @dotancohen fixed it with `code`iconv('CP1256', 'UTF-8', $it->getSubPathName());`code` :D thanks @Fred -ii-

Comment: That's great news, glad it worked out @emadiga and you're welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, convert the text to UTF-8:

```
iconv('CP1256', 'UTF-8', $it->getSubPathName());
```

Then, ensure that the web browser properly decodes the page as UTF-8. Put this as the top of your PHP file:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");

// The rest of the code
```

Comment: Try now, I've changed the function for encoding to UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks That's Worked but make it in new var $NewName=iconv('CP1256', 'UTF-8',$it->getSubPatchName()); then echo $NewName; THANKS A LOT :D